# Camera render without a texture view

Tags: java, android

I have downloaded a project from GitHub ( https://github.com/Ma-Dan/AndroidFaceMask?files=1 ) for mask detection. it is working fine. In that camera is rendering on a texture view. But I don't need a texture view or surface view. But the camera should be rendering. what should I do? please assist me. I need to know it is possible or not.

Comment: SurfaceView and TextureView are surfaces for Camera. If you want camera, you must have them.

Comment: thanks for the reply @AlanDeep